# Export a function in a Shared Module

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 12 I have the following function:

```
export function equalValidator(first: string, second: string): ValidatorFn {

  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    // Code
  };

}
```

To use it I need to import it in each component:

```
import { equalValidator } from '../shared/equal-validator';
```

How to include it in a SharedModule and export it to different components?

Or shouldn't I include functions in a Shared module?

Comment: You can always group your helpful functions in a `UtilitiesService` which you then provide within your sharedmodule. But that seems to me like a lot of really unnecessary boiler plate code.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate folder for my custom functions that you can call from any component. And then have modules only in your shared "module".